# How to handle a datatype change of a field in datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I haven't been able to find any discussion about this. In particular, I am wondering:

- Can one just change the datatype of a field in Objectify, e.g. from `List<String>` to a custom class? (I'm guessing yes.)
- Is it possible to use annotations like `@IgnoreLoad` or `@AlsoLoad` to ignore entries in the old datatype? (Or more generally, to migrate the old entries to the new datatype on the go?) This is documented for fields with different names, but I'm worried this is impossible if the name stays the same.
- Is it still possible to load the table into BigQuery (via datastore backups) if a field has entries in two different datatypes?
- Is it relevant whether all the old entries are `null`?

Alternative solutions are to reload/save all the old entries and to use a different field name, but I am specifically interested in the questions listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Of course you can. But your existing data would become inaccessible. Since a list of String (or a list of any other `Serializable` class) is serialized by Objectify, so the actual datatype in the datastore will stay a string.
2. As you said this is possible with different names. I don't see how it could be possible with the same value because all that serialization stuff is black-boxed for you. <strike>Thinking about it... **Alternative Solution:** Why don't you change the type of your field to String, do the conversion and change the datatype to the intended one? You'd have to imitate the serialization style of Objectify but that should be doable.</strike> (Have to rethink this, see comment by @stickfigure)
3. Yes and no. Yes in your case the data is a string and will stay a string. However if you'd use nested schemas in BQ this would not work since your schema changes.
4. Nope. When all entities of your class have a null in a specific field it will disappear in the datastore viewer as well.

Comment: Thanks! 1. In what sense inaccessible? 2. I don't understand your alternative solution. You seem to imply the custom class I want to change to will be serialised as a string, but I don't know that that's true and I don't understand how that matters. To clarify, I want to prevent the loading of old entries with the wrong datatype. 3. So why "yes in my case"? Say if I change from String to int, BigQuery couldn't handle that right? 4. So yes it is relevant? Does a field that is null everywhere in effect not exist?

Comment: The answer to all you questions boils down to the data type in the datastore (not the one used by objectify). A collection or array of any kind is serialized to a String value by objectify. Thus the underlying datatype is always String for Strings and all Collections / Arrays. If you change the type to a primitive type like long objectify would not be able to read the value and upon the next save of the entity overwrite that value. If you import a dump into bigquery and you have different primitive types in a field it is probably going to use the greatest common denominator which is a string.

Comment: As for the solution: This would be a way to convert your data to a new format if both the old and the new format is expressible as string (String, Collection, Array). If you set the field type to string you'd get the raw content and you could rewrite that content according to your needs. Then you could change the type to an embedded format if that is what you rewrote your data to. Switching from a complex type or Strings to a different primitive type will only be possible with an additional field, if you wish to keep your data.

Comment: Regarding No 4: To my knowledge you'd have to set all fields of that entity to null and remove the field from your entity class. That would make the field disappear. But a null value basically doesn't exist in the datastore as it makes no sense to store no data (now that sounds really dumb - oh well).

Comment: Well, as I said in this particular case I don't need to keep the data. In fact I believe it is null everywhere, if empty lists are indeed stored as null. So I guess I can freely change the datatype with no negative consequences.

Comment: (The part I am still not completely clear about is where you seem to imply that objectify won't have problems loading fields of a datatype that are underlyingly String (as opposed to e.g. int). Upon loading, Objectify will try to convert these back to the relevant datatype, and will give an error if that's not possible, right?)

Comment: Mh, i think it will silently discard the data if it cannot read the value. If there is an error you could use the method i mentioned and in a first step set the value to String, go through all entities and set it to null. Once everything is null you can change the type to whatever you wish. +stickfigure care to comment?

Comment: Sorry konqi, you are incorrect about how Objectify stores things. A List<String> is stored as a list of strings. There's no strange conversion to a String form - although if you change the field to type String, Objectify *will* convert whatever native value was there to a String. Very unlikely to be what the OP wants. I'll make a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Objectify's documentation includes a section on schema migration:

https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/SchemaMigration

Almost any kind of migration is possible using the primitives provided (@OnLoad, @OnSave, @AlsoLoad, @IgnoreSave, etc). It's really quite specific to the change you want to make. The easiest approach conceptually is to create a new field with a different name and the new type and then use an @OnLoad method to import the data. If you want to rename the field back, you can do that in a second pass.

More complex would be to import the data in a 'raw' form (say, change the type of the field to Object) and then convert it in place with @OnLoad. This can be tricky and probably isn't a good idea unless you really know what you're doing.

Keep in mind that if you have a busy system, when you switch versions, there's a very brief period of time when both the old version and the new version are both serving. So to avoid trashing data, your system needs to pass through a state in which both the old version and the new version understand both schemas.

Comment: Thanks for expanding your comment into a post! I've seen that page, but it doesn't discuss changing the type of a field without changing its name. And from what you say I gather that the answer to my second question is no. (I guess what I was hoping for is @ignoreload taking some conditions, like on datatype.)

Comment: I added an example for you

Comment: The example is very helpful. But I don't understand how you can specify `@AlsoLoad("foo") String value` in `importOldFoo`, given that the new values of `foo` won't be of `String` type (i.e. what happens when you load an entity that has already been converted?)

Comment: Yeah, my mistake - up waaay too many hours in a row. Sorry. Nevermind that section; use two fields.